# Suppose that $\|a\| = \|b \| = 1$ and $ a \neq b$. Prove that $\|ka + (1-k)b \| < 1 $ for all $0<k<1$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\|a\| = \|b \| = 1$ and $ a \neq b$. 
Prove that $\|ka + (1-k)b \| < 1 $ for all $0<k<1$

I tried 
$$\|ka + (1-k)b \|$$
$$\leq \|ka \| + \|(1-k)b \|$$
$$=|k|\|a\| + |(1-k)|\|b \|$$
$$=1$$

However, i got a less than or equal to, rather than strictly less than. How can i fix this?

Comment: What does $\|a\|$ mean?  Some kind of norm on some space?  If so, which norm and which space?

Comment: it's norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: you cannot quit the "less equal" except in the case that it is an inner product space

Comment: Can you see the geometrical side of it which is fairly obvious?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh unfortunately, not really...

Comment: Well vectors $a, b$ are two different radii of a circle of unit radius. Let $O$ be centre and $P, Q $ be points on it so that $OP, OQ$ are two radii. The vector $ka+(1-k)b$ gives a point $R$ on line segment $PQ$ and since circle is convex, the point $R$ lies inside circle so that it's norm is less than radius $1$.

Comment: One can show using geometrical means that a chord of circle lies entirely inside the circle (apart from two endpoints which lie on circle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the vectors belong to some inner product space then
$$
\|ka+(1-k)b\|^2=k^2+(1-k)^2+2k(1-k)\operatorname{Re}\langle a,b \rangle\tag1
$$
and of course we have also the estimate
$$
\|ka+(1-k)b\|\leqslant k\|a\|+(1-k)\|b\|= 1\tag2
$$
Then the RHS of $\mathrm{(1)} $ is equal to $1$ if and only if $\operatorname{Re}\langle a,b \rangle=\|a\|\|b\|=1$, but this would imply that $a$ and $b$ are colinear, what would imply that $a=b$ in this case, therefore from $\mathrm{(2)} $ and the previous result $\operatorname{Re}\langle a,b \rangle=r<1$ and we conclude that $\|ka+(1-k)b\|<1$ for all $k\in(0,1)$.

However for arbitrary norm the identity $\|ka+(1-k)b\|<1$ does not hold, by example consider the norm in $\Bbb R ^2$ defined by $\|(x_1,x_2)\|=\max\{|x_1|,|x_2|\}$, $a:=(0,1)$ and $b:=(1,1)$.

Comment: Hi, so i need to combine two equation to get < 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the used norm is deduced from a inner product, the case of equality in triangular inequality $\|x+y\| \leq  \|x\| + \|y\|$ corresponds to $y=\alpha x$ or $x= \alpha y$ forme some $\alpha \geq 0$. Applying this to the case presented above, we obtain: $b=\alpha a$ or $a=\alpha b$ for some $\alpha \geq 0$. Since $\|a\|=\|b\|=1$ this gives  $\alpha=1$ then $a=b$, which is not true.

Comment: But my goal is to prove it true... so the question itself is wrong?

Comment: No the question is true. On the other hand, the result that I proposed concerning the case of equality in triangular inequality is a known result. It is easily deduced from the case of equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.